# How to generate Security Compliance report for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-sdk

**Any security compliance of aws code samples?**

Suppose I want to check following things :-

```
a)Security groups
  security - open ports, SG, keys, Protocols

b)ELB security
  exposed ports

c)ec2
  SG, exposed ports, instances must be configured in vpc

d)IAM:
Full admin privilege in IAM policy, user-level MFA status, password policy status

e)lambda :
admin role, unauthorized cross-account access
```

How to collect this information through code? Is there any aws java sdk avaliable to check this things?

I found one tool Chef Inspec where i can write rule and get report but can't able to pass list of instances, it check for instance by instance..
Is there any other tool or java sdk to get all these things?